# Convert dates timezone in Java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I have the below function which takes the date as a String parameter and converts that date into the BST timezone with the required format. I have shared the two cases and case 2 it does not convert the given value to the BST or London time zone.

```
  private String changeToBSTTimeZone(String date) {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(date);
    ZoneId londonZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    ZonedDateTime londonDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, londonZone);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
    return londonDateTime.format(formatter);
  }
```

**Case 1: Working**

Parameter value: 2023-03-29T01:20:10Z

Output: 29 Mar 2023 02:20:10 am BST

**Case 2: Not Working**

Parameter value: 2023-03-23T14:10:10Z

Output: 23 Mar 2023 02:10:10 pm GMT

Comment: Why would you want to output a date at 23th march in **British Summer Time**? Summer time in the UK starts on the 25th march. Before that they do not use BST and GMT is correct.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Do you mean the output is correct and before summer time starts both GMT and UK time will be same?

Comment: Yes.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: UK is on GMT during standard time. So yes, your observed output is correct. Considering that GMT is for Greenwich Mean Time and Greenwich is in the eastern outskirts of London, this may not be very surprising?